# How can I invoke my API which designed on API MANAGER?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager, wso2-cloud, wso2-esb

> I want to invoke my API which designed on API MANAGER. I do it as the following screenshot. But there is no correct result as the following screenshot. 
>      Before I do the above saying, I do the curl command and get correct result.

Then how can I resovle the problem?

Comment: Enable the wirelog, hit the api and attach the wirelog to the question .
http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Comment: why the URL can be  invoked with the curl command but did not in google's postman.

Comment: if you enable wirelog, it will  help to identify whether request hits the server or not. if request does not hit the server it is and issue with the postman. thus you can isolate the problem first.

Comment: Try opening the link in the browser to see if it's a ssl error.

Comment: I opened it in the browser and the browser appeared ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I doubt if the url could be invoked by HttpClient

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why The API could not be invoked by postman or httpclient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390291/why-the-api-could-not-be-invoked-by-postman-or-httpclient)

Comment: you are right ...

Comment: Then how can I invoke the API with httpclient? @Bhathiya I Use the 214 ip address ,there is error logs:org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 124.251.62.214:8243 [/124.251.62.214] failed: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do call tracing and troubleshooting in API Cloud: http://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/trace-api-calls-and-responses/