# why The API could not be invoked by postman or httpclient?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

The API's Ip address is 172.17.0.1. Thus, I invoke it in  postman,how can The browse or postman find the ip address? and I think it is the reason why postman or browse could not invoke the API gererated by AM

Comment: That's internal network IP. Can you ping it? Are you sure the server is up?

Comment: I do ping and not access. The server is up . I can run curl commond to invoke my API successfully

Comment: Can you share the curl input & output?

Comment: v1@ubuntu03:~$ curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer d7577f4d-8cc0-3e99-a819-c70472eb0bc9' 'https://localhost:8243/V1.0.2/stock/getParam?age=sdf'
sdf

Comment: Uhh, just use http://localhost:8243 instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131876/discussion-between-martheen-and-mike).

Comment: yeah ,It alse did not work.

Comment: Is the browser and server in the same machine?

Comment: No,the server is deploied on linux . and I visite it in my Windows system

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to invoke a private IP.

Also, I don't think what you are trying to call is an API in WSO2 API cloud. URLs of APIs in WSO2 API cloud look like this.

```
http://gateway.api.cloud.wso2.com/t/mytenant/pizzashack/1.0.0
```

Comment: Then ,how can I find the URLS of APIS in WSO2 API cloud. I do not find where show the URL.   For example, where is the URL of API which I designed "172.17.0.1:8243/V1.0.2/stock/getParam?age=sdf'"

Comment: Just login to store and click on your API.

Comment: yeah ,I click My API and there is no the API of generateed by AM .Would you tell me that whici place I can see or find the API of generated by AM.

Comment: What you say is not clear. Post a screenshot after clicking your API.

Comment: plz have a look  the screenshot
https://imagebin.ca/v/378oBBWBhxvU
https://ibin.co/378oBBWBhxvU.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131910/discussion-between-bhathiya-and-mike).

Answer (score 2):

As per the chat we had, you should use your public IP instead of private one if you need external parties to access your APIs.